# Replacement for Sitecore.Context.Database.Name in JSS?

Tags: jss

is there any replacement for Sitecore.Context.Database.Name in JSS..?

just trying to know the list of conteproperties are ac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, JSS route data contains the database name for the requested item, e.g. `sitecore.route.databaseName`.

Also, you may want to look into extending the Layout Service context data if you need the data outside of the route: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/extending-layout-service/layoutservice-extending-context

Comment: Thank you Adam.. I can able to access the DB name using the below property sitecoreContext.route.databaseName.. also i tried extending the layout service context data, looks cool..